# Linking issue whe compiling cpp code with gmplib on Windows

Tags: c++, file, class, gmp

I'm having some issues compiling my code below and I think the problem is related to linking gmplib to the compiler.

I couldn't understand how to set the lib up on Windows or how to compile it. Here is my code. Variable names and comments are written in French. Sorry for that.

```
// projet(essai final).cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//****** la classe rsa_gmp.h ******* 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <gmp.h> 
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


class Class_one {
private:
    string fichierSource;
    string fichierDest;
    int tailleBloc ;
public:  
    Class_one();
    void PGCD (mpz_t ,mpz_t,mpz_t);
    void puissance(mpz_t,mpz_t,mpz_t,mpz_t);
    void test_primalite(mpz_t,mpz_t);
    void InitialiseRandom(gmp_randstate_t );
    void nextprime (mpz_ptr , mpz_srcptr ) ;
    void Genere_publicKey( mpz_t  ,mpz_t  , mpz_t ,gmp_randstate_t  ); 
    void Genere_privateKey (mpz_t  , mpz_t  , mpz_t ) ; 
    void Genere_nbPremier( mpz_t , mpz_t , int , gmp_randstate_t  ) ; 
    void chiffre_Msg( mpz_t , mpz_t , mpz_t , mpz_t );  
    void dechiffre_Msg( mpz_t , mpz_t  , mpz_t , mpz_t ); 
    short int SetFichiers(string nomFichierDest, string nomFichierSource);
    string DeTranscoder(mpz_t  );
    mpz_t Transcoder(string ) ;
    ~Class_one();
}


Class_one::Class_one(){

    this->fichierDest="";
    this->fichierSource="";
    this->tailleBloc=256;
};
Class_one::~Class_one(){};

void  Class_one::PGCD ( mpz_t resultat, mpz_t a , mpz_t b ) 
{ 
    mpz_t r , r1 ,r2; 

    //intialiser les variables 
    mpz_init( r ); 
    mpz_init( r1 ); 
    mpz_init( r2 ); 

    // affectation 
    mpz_set (r , a ) ; 
    mpz_set (r1 , b) ; 

    while ( mpz_cmp_ui ( r1, 0) != 0) 
    { 
        mpz_mod ( r2, r, r1); 
        mpz_set (r , r1 ) ; 
        mpz_set (r1 , r2) ; 
    } 

    mpz_set (resultat , r) ; 
    // liberer l'espace de variable 
    mpz_clear( r ); 
    mpz_clear( r1 ); 
    mpz_clear( r2 ); 

} 


void Class_one::puissance (mpz_t resultat ,mpz_t a, mpz_t e, mpz_t n) 
{ 
    mpz_t temp,t,a_bis,e_bis ; 
    // initialise la variable local 
    mpz_init( temp ); 
    mpz_init( t ); 

    mpz_init( a_bis ); 
    mpz_set( a_bis , a ); 

    mpz_init( e_bis ); 
    mpz_set( e_bis , e ); 

    mpz_set_ui (temp , 1); 

    while ( mpz_cmp_ui ( e_bis,0 )> 0) 
    { 
        mpz_mod_ui( t , e_bis , 2); 
        if( mpz_cmp_ui( t , 0 ) != 0) 
        { 
            mpz_mul( temp , temp , a_bis); 
            mpz_mod( temp , temp ,n ); 
        } 
        mpz_mul(a_bis , a_bis, a_bis); 
        mpz_mod ( a_bis, a_bis, n); 

        mpz_tdiv_q_ui(e_bis,e_bis,2); 
    } 

    mpz_set( resultat , temp ); 
    // liberer l'espace utilisé 
    mpz_clear( temp );mpz_clear(t); 
    mpz_clear(a_bis );mpz_clear(e_bis ); 

} 


/* 
La test_primalite verifie si un nombre est premier,c'est une application 
de Miller_Rabin 
@ param long a, n( mod n) 
@return 1 ou 0 
*/ 
void Class_one::test_primalite ( mpz_t resultat , mpz_t n) 
{ 
    mpz_t var ,p, e, m , i , k ,temp ; 
    // initialiser les variables locals 
    mpz_init(var) ;mpz_init(p) ;mpz_init(e) ;mpz_init( temp ) ; 
    mpz_init( m) ;mpz_init( i) ;mpz_init( k) ; 

    mpz_sub_ui ( m , n , 1); 
    mpz_sub_ui ( e , n , 1); 
    mpz_set_ui( var , 10 ); 

    mpz_set_ui ( k , 0 ); 
    mpz_mod_ui ( temp , e , 2); 

    while ( mpz_cmp_ui ( temp , 0 )== 0) 
    { 
        mpz_tdiv_q_ui( e , e , 2); 
        mpz_add_ui ( k , k , 1); 
        mpz_mod_ui ( temp , e , 2); 
    } 

    Class_one::puissance( mpz_t p ,mpz_t var ,mpz_t  e , mpz_t n ); 

    if( mpz_cmp_ui ( p , 1) == 0) 
    { 
        mpz_set_ui( resultat , 1); 
        return; 
    } 

    mpz_set_ui( i , 0); 

    while( mpz_cmp ( i , k ) < 0) 
    { 
        if( mpz_cmp( p , m )== 0) 
        { 
            mpz_set_ui( resultat , 1); 
            break ; 
        } 

        if( mpz_cmp_ui( p , 1 )== 0) 
        { 
            mpz_set_ui( resultat , 0); 
            break ; 
        } 

        mpz_mul( p, p , p ); 
        mpz_mod( p , p , n) ; 

        mpz_add_ui (i, i , 1); 
    } 


    // liberer l'espace utilisé par les variables locals 
    mpz_init(var) ;mpz_init(p) ; mpz_init(e) ;mpz_init(temp) ; 
    mpz_init( m) ;mpz_init( i) ;mpz_init( k) ; 
} 


// la fonction initializeRandom permet d,initialiser le generateur de nombre aleatoire 
void Class_one::InitialiseRandom(gmp_randstate_t r_state ) 
{ 
    /* Initialisation de nombre aleatoire*/ 
    unsigned long int seed; 
    seed = time(0); 

    gmp_randinit_default (r_state); 
    gmp_randseed_ui(r_state, seed); 
} 


// le nextprime permet de calculer le nombre premier suivant 
void Class_one::nextprime (mpz_ptr p, mpz_srcptr t) 
{ 
    mpz_t test ; 
    mpz_init( test ); 
    mpz_add_ui (p, t, 13); 

    void Class_one::test_primalite ( mpz_t test ,mpz_t  p); 
    while (mpz_cmp_ui( test , 0)!= 1 ) 
    { 
        mpz_add_ui (p, p, 13); 
        void Class_one::test_primalite ( mpz_t test , mpz_t p); 
    } 

} 



// la fonction genere_PK() permet de créer la clé public e 

void Class_one:: Genere_publicKey( mpz_t e ,mpz_t p , mpz_t q ,gmp_randstate_t state ) 
{ 
    mpz_t a , b , c, r , y ,rand_Num; 

    // initialiser les avriable locale 
    mpz_init( a ); 
    mpz_init( b ); 
    mpz_init( c ); 
    mpz_init( y ); 
    mpz_init( r ); 
    mpz_init( rand_Num ); 

    mpz_sub_ui( a, p, 1 ); 
    mpz_sub_ui( b, q, 1 ); 

    mpz_mul( y, a, b ); 

    //Définition d'une valeur max de E. 
    mpz_t max; 
    mpz_init( max ); 
    mpz_set_str ( max , "97" ,0); 

    mpz_urandomm( rand_Num, state, max ); 
    mpz_add_ui ( rand_Num , rand_Num , 3); 
    mpz_mod(c,rand_Num,y); 
    void Class_one::PGCD( mpz_t r , mpz_t c, mpz_t y); 

    while (( mpz_cmp_ui( r,1 )!= 0) ||mpz_cmp( c ,max )>0 ||mpz_cmp_ui( c ,0) ==0 ) 
    { 
        mpz_urandomm( rand_Num, state, max ); 
        mpz_add_ui ( rand_Num , rand_Num , 3); 
        mpz_mod(c,rand_Num,y); 
        void Class_one::PGCD( mpz_t r , mpz_t c, mpz_t y); 
    } 
    mpz_set( e ,c ) ; 
    // effacer les espaces utilisées par les variables 
    mpz_clear( a );mpz_clear( b );mpz_clear( y );mpz_clear( r ); 
    mpz_clear( rand_Num );mpz_clear( max );mpz_clear( c ); 


} 



// La fonction genere_privateKey permet de determiner la clé public 
// algorithme euclide etendu 
void Class_one::Genere_privateKey (mpz_t d , mpz_t e , mpz_t phi) 
{ 
    mpz_t e0,t0 , t , q, r, n0, temp ,temp2; 

    // initialiser les variables 
    mpz_init ( e0);mpz_init ( t0 );mpz_init ( t );mpz_init ( q ); 
    mpz_init ( r );mpz_init ( n0 );mpz_init ( temp );mpz_init ( temp2 ); 

    mpz_set_ui( t , 1) ; 
    mpz_set ( n0 , phi ); 
    mpz_set ( e0 , e ); 
    mpz_tdiv_q( q , n0 , e0); 
    mpz_mod ( r ,n0 , e0) ; 

    while( mpz_cmp_ui ( r, 0) > 0) 
    { 
        mpz_mul( temp , q, t); 
        mpz_sub( temp , t0, temp ); 

        if( mpz_cmp_ui ( temp , 0) >= 0) 
        { 
            mpz_mod ( temp , temp ,phi); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            mpz_mod( temp , temp , phi); 
        } 

        mpz_set( t0 , t); 
        mpz_set( t , temp); 
        mpz_set( n0, e0); 
        mpz_set( e0, r); 
        mpz_tdiv_q( q , n0 , e0); 
        mpz_mod ( r ,n0 , e0) ; 

    } 
    mpz_set ( d , t); 
    // liberer l'espaces des variables 
    mpz_clear( e0 );mpz_clear( t0 );mpz_clear( t );mpz_clear( q ); 
    mpz_clear( r );mpz_clear( n0 );mpz_clear( temp );mpz_clear( temp2 ); 
} 




/* 
La fonction Genere_nbPremier retourne les deux entiers P et Q 
aleatoires et premiers 
*/ 

void Class_one::Genere_nbPremier( mpz_t p, mpz_t q, int n, gmp_randstate_t state ) 
{ 
    //création de varaiable locale 
    mpz_t rand, nb_aleatoire, max , min , varp , varq; 

    // initialiser les variables 
    mpz_init( rand ); mpz_init( nb_aleatoire ); mpz_init( max ); 
    mpz_init( min );mpz_init( varp );mpz_init( varq ); 

    // calcule du Borne Superieur 
    mpz_ui_pow_ui( max, 2, n+1 ); 
    // calcule du borne inferieur 
    mpz_ui_pow_ui( min, 2, n ); 

    // Génère un nombre compris entre 0 et max et le stocke dans rand. state initialise le générateur aléatoire. 
    do 
    { 
        mpz_urandomm( rand, state, max ); 

    }while( mpz_cmp( rand, min) > 0 ); 
    // Vérifie que rand est supérieur à la borne inférieure 
    void Class_one::nextprime ( mpz_ptr p ,mpz_srcptr  rand ); 

    // Génère un nombre Q compris entre 0 et max et le stocke dans rand. state initialise le générateur aléatoire. 
    do 
    { 
        mpz_urandomm( nb_aleatoire, state, max ); 

    }while(( mpz_cmp( nb_aleatoire, min) > 0 )|| ( mpz_cmp ( p , q ) == 0)); 
    // Vérifie que rand est supérieur à la borne inférieure 
    void Class_one::nextprime(mpz_ptr q ,mpz_srcptr  nb_aleatoire ); 

    // clear l'espace utilisé 
    mpz_clear( nb_aleatoire );mpz_clear( rand );mpz_clear( max ); 
    mpz_clear( min );mpz_clear( varq );mpz_clear( varp ); 

} 

// fonction de chiffrement de message 
void Class_one::chiffre_Msg( mpz_t chiffre, mpz_t message , mpz_t e, mpz_t n) 
{ 
    mpz_t cipher; 
    mpz_t i; 
    mpz_t temp; 

    mpz_init(cipher); 
    mpz_init(i); 
    mpz_init(temp); 
    mpz_set_si(cipher,1); 

    void Class_one::puissance (mpz_t cipher ,mpz_t message,mpz_t  e,mpz_t  n); 
    mpz_set(chiffre,cipher); 

    mpz_clear(cipher); 
    mpz_clear(temp); 
} 


// fonction dechiffrement de message 
void Class_one:: dechiffre_Msg( mpz_t message2, mpz_t chiffre , mpz_t d, mpz_t n) 
{ 
    mpz_t message; 
    mpz_t i; 
    mpz_t temp; 

    mpz_init(message); 
    mpz_init(i); 
    mpz_init(temp); 
    mpz_set(temp,chiffre); 

    void Class_one::puissance ( mpz_t message,mpz_t temp ,mpz_t  d,mpz_t  n); 
    mpz_set(message2,message); 

    mpz_clear(message); 
    mpz_clear(temp); 
} 

short int Class_one::SetFichiers(string nomFichierDest, string nomFichierSource)
{
    FILE *f1;
    FILE *f2;
    f1=fopen(nomFichierSource.c_str(), "rb");
    f2=fopen(nomFichierDest.c_str(), "wb");

    if(f1==NULL || f2==NULL)
    {
        if (f1!=NULL)   fclose(f1);
        if (f2!=NULL)   fclose(f2);
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    this->fichierDest=""+nomFichierDest;
    this->fichierSource=""+nomFichierSource;
    return 0;
}
mpz_t Class_one::Transcoder(string str)/* 
La méthode Transcoder : Cette méthode prend une chaine de caractères, puis la transforme en un nombre équivalent. Le nombre est égale à la somme du
code ascii dernier caractère, l’avant dernier multiplié par 256, l’avant avant dernier multiplié par 2562…etc
*/
{
    mpz_t Somme;
    mpz_t var;
    mpz_t M;
    mpz_t Mul;
    mpz_t resultat ;
    signed long long int i;
    //initialisation des variables 
    mpz_init(Somme);mpz_init(var);
    mpz_init(Mul);
    mpz_init(resultat);

    //affectation
    mpz_set_ui(M,1);


    for(i=(signed long long int)(str.length()-1); i>=0; i--)
    {


        aux =(unsigned char)str[(unsigned int)i];//La classe string est composé de signed char
        void Class_one::puissance(mpz_t resultat ,mpz_t  256 , mpz_t i, mpzt n);
        mpz_mul(Mul,resultat,aux);
        mpz_add(Somme,Somme, Mul);
    }
    return Somme ;
    mpz_clear(Somme);mpz_clear(var);mpz_clear(Mul);mpz_clear(resultat);
}

string Class_one::DeTranscoder(mpz_t  msg)
/*La méthode DeTranscoder : En prenant un nombre en paramètre,
elle génère une chaine de caractères équivalente, le nombre va être divisé par 256 en concaténant la chaine 
déjà trouvée et le caractère dont le code ascii est le reste de la division par 256.*/

{
    mpz_t div;
    mpz_t aux;
    mpz_t reste;
    string str;
    //initialiser les variables 
    mpz_init(div);mpz_init(aux);mpz_init(reste);
    // affectation 
    mpz_set(aux,msg);
    mpz_set_ui(div,256);
    while(aux.size()>1 || aux!=0)
    {
        aux=mpz_div(aux, div, reste);
        str=(char)reste + str;
    }
    return str;
    //liberer  les variables 
    mpz_clear(div); mpz_clear(aux); mpz_clear(reste);
}


class Cryptage{
    void crypter_RSA();
}

// la fonction principal du rsa en mode Standard 

void Cryptage::crypter_RSA() 
{ 
    // Variable locales 
    mpz_t p , q , e,d , n , phi , message,msg_chiffre,cipher ; 
    int choix ;

    //initialiser les variables locales 
    mpz_init(msg_chiffre);  mpz_init(cipher);
    mpz_init(e); mpz_init(n); mpz_init(p); 
    mpz_init(q); mpz_init(d); mpz_init(phi); 
    ;mpz_init( message); 

    // initialisationn du generateur 
    gmp_randstate_t state; 
    Class_one::InitialiseRandom(gmp_randstate_t state); 
    Class_one::Genere_nbPremier(mpz_t  p,mpz_tq ,mpz_t 512, gmp_randstate_t state); 

    // la valeur de N 
    mpz_mul ( n , p , q); 

    // les variablesP et Q 
    gmp_printf ("\n\n \t P \t: \t%Zd \n", p ); 
    gmp_printf ("\n\n \t Q \t: \t%Zd \n", q ); 

    // Generer la clé public 
    Class_one::Genere_publicKey( mpz_t e, mpz_t p ,mpz_t q , gmp_randstate_t state); 
    gmp_printf("\n\n \t clef pubic : \t%Zd \n",e); 

    // Calculer la valeur de phi 
    mpz_sub_ui( p , p , 1); 
    mpz_sub_ui( q , q , 1); 
    mpz_mul( phi , p , q) ; 

    // genere la cle privee 
    Class_one::Genere_privateKey (mpz_t d ,mpz_t e , mpz_t phi ); 
    gmp_printf("\n\n \t clef prive : \t%Zd \n",d); 

    // set fichier 
    short int index= Class_one::SetFichiers(string nomFichierDest, string nomFichierSource);
    while (index!=0) {
    index= Class_one::SetFichiers(string nomFichierDest, string nomFichierSource);
    } 

    // le message a chiffre // le message a chiffre 
    printf("\n\n\n\t Entrez le message a crypter: "); 
    gmp_scanf("%Zd",&message); 

    cout<<"entrer \n 1)crypter\ n2)decrypter "<<endl;
    cin>>choix;
    switch(choix)
    {
    case 1 :
    //dechiffrement du message 
          unsigned long long int j,nbZero,m;
        FILE *f1;        
        FILE *f2;
        string str;
        string str2="e";
        string str3;
        mpz_t  msg;
        if(fichierSource.length()<1) break ;
        f1=fopen(this->fichierSource.c_str(), "rb");
        f2=fopen(this->fichierDest.c_str(), "wb");
        fseek(f1,0,SEEK_SET);
        for(j=0,m=1, nbZero=0;j<8;j++,m*=256) nbZero+=fgetc(f1)*m;
        str2[0]=fgetc(f1);
        while(str2[0]!=EOF)
        {
            str=""+str2;
            for(j=1;j<this->tailleBloc_; j++)
            {
                str2[0]=fgetc(f1);
                str=str+ str2 ;
            }
            str2[0]=fgetc(f1);

            msg=Class_one::Transcoder(str);
            Class_one::CrypterDecrypter(mpz_t msg,mpz_t ,mpz_t ,mpz_t);

            if (str2[0]==EOF)
            {
                for(j=0;j<(this->tailleBloc - nbZero); j++)
                    fputc((int)str[j], f2);
            }
            else
                for(j=0;j<this->tailleBloc ; j++)   fputc((int)str[j], f2);
        }
        fclose(f1);
        fclose(f2);

    Class_one::dechiffre_Msg (mpz_t cipher, mpz_t msg_chiffre ,mpz_t d ,mpz_t n); 
    gmp_printf("\n\n\t Le message dechiffre :\t%Zd\n\n",cipher); 
    break ;

    case 2 :
    //chiffrement du message 
    mpz_init_set_str(cipher, "1",0); 
     unsigned long long int j,aux;
            FILE *f1, *f2;
            unsigned char c;
            unsigned long long int nbZero ;
            string str ;
            string str2="e";
            mpz_t  msg;

            if(fichierSource.length()<1) return -1;
            f1=fopen(this->fichierSource.c_str(), "rb");
            f2=fopen(this->fichierDest.c_str(), "wb");
            str2[0]=fgetc(f1);
            if (str2[0]==EOF) break ;
            fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);
            //fpos_t <==> long long int pour notre compilateur
            fgetpos(f1,(fpos_t *)&nbZero);
            nbZero=nbZero%this->tailleBloc;
            if(nbZero!=0) nbZero=this->tailleBloc - nbZero;

            aux=nbZero;
            for(j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
                c=aux%256;
                aux=aux/256;
                fputc(c,f2);
            }

            fseek(f1,0, SEEK_SET);
            str2[0]=fgetc(f1);
            while(str2[0]!=EOF)
            {
                str=""+str2;
                for(j=1;j<(this->tailleBloc); j++)
                {
                    str2[0]=fgetc(f1);
                    str=str+str2 ;
                }
                str2[0]=fgetc(f1);
                if(str2[0]==EOF)
                {
                    for(j=this->tailleBloc-nbZero; j< this->tailleBloc; j++)
                        str[j]=0;
                }
                /*for(j=str.length();j<this->tailleBloc_; j++)
                    str=str2+str;*/
                msg=Class_one::Transcoder(str);
                Class_one::chiffre_Msg(mpz_t msg , mpz_t msg  ,  mpz_t e  , mpz_t n );
                str=Class_one::DeTranscoder(msg);
                for(j=str.length();j<this->tailleBloc_; j++)
                        fputc((int)0, f2);
                for(j=0;j<str.length(); j++)
                        fputc((int)str[j], f2);
            }
            fclose(f1);
            fclose(f2);

    break ;
    }
    // liberer les variables locales 
    mpz_clear(p); mpz_clear(q);
    mpz_clear(e);mpz_clear(phi);mpz_clear(n); 
    mpz_clear(message);mpz_clear( msg_chiffre);


} 
int main (){
    void Cryptage::crypter_RSA();


}
```

Comment: You need to say which compiler you are using, and what the error message says. Without that information it's not going to be easy to help.

Comment: What error does the compiler give you?

Comment: gmp is very difficult to set up on Windows. You should use [MPIR](http://mpir.org/), which is a version of gmp specially modified for Windows.

Comment: @user914710 as with others, compiler information required here. there are a lot of C++ compilers for Windows out there and they use different ways to link to external libraries.

Comment: @john very difficult? I have no problem working with it. configure/make/install/use-ing works smoothly with gcc here.

Comment: @john, i need more infos about MPIR, maybe short intro about it and howto use it :) thanks. I'm sure it will help her too.

Comment: You think you're having linking issues, so you post a mountain of code without posting the linker error messages? Also, you forgot to replace the `++version++` with the actual version numbers, although if it is a linking issue that shouldn't be relevant

Comment: @LeleDumbo: I had a feeling that installing gcc on a Windows system would be beyond the OP (and a later post confirms that they are trying to use Visual Studio).

Comment: @Jacer Omri: I think the MPIR web-site is the best place to get that information.

Comment: @john ok, that's a valid assumption on Windows

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to install/build GMP as well as MPIR on Windows. Very difficult. Need to compile and build libraries first etc.

After a while i found **C++ Big Integer Library from Matt McCutchen**

https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

C++ source code only. Very simple to use. Integrated within 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Some advice, even if it's not really an answer... You can't work like that, even for such a small project: you have to tackle one problem at a time.

Basically, you tried to write your whole program, and *then* only to compile it: you need to write your different functions and test them separately, especially since you are a beginner.

For instance, if you want to compile with gmplib, write something like this:

```
#include <gmp.h>

int main ()
{
    mpz_t x;
    return 0;
}
```

try to compile it and see what happens. If you have a compilation error, you will have a small piece of code that you can post here: add the exact message of your compiler, and the people here will help you instead of closing your question (again...).

This would be the *first* problem: compiling with another library. Once this works, you can add a *small* piece of your own code, recompile it and test what you have so far.

For instance, add your class declaration with a minimal definition for the functions: don't write the implementation, just a nearly empty body, e.g:

```
class OneClass {
   void pgcd (mpz_t, mpz_t, mpz_t) { /* empty function */ }
   // etc
};
```

you will be able (hopfully, it will be easy) to spot that you miss a semicolon at the end of your class declaration, and that your Transcoder function return a mpz_t, wich is illegal because mpz_t is a typedef for an array.

Then, when this works, add the implementations of your function one by one, in an order that allow you to test them *as you write them*.

You will be much more efficient, as it will be easier for you to know *where* you problem comes from.

In short, finding an error in the two lines you just added (if you know the rest is correct) is easy, but finding all the errors in such a big file is long and painfull...

Write one piece of code, compile it, test it and then only write the next one: it will pay !

Edit: actually, you will need to *use* one function in the library to test if you can link with it properly, but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

GMP does not work with Visual Studio, you should use [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/) instead. You won't need to change your code, just the library you use.

Comment: @user914710: You should look at the [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/) web-site. There is also an introduction in French http://tcuvelier.developpez.com/tutoriels/c/mpir/introduction/

Comment: 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: projet(essai final), Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 26/08/2011 22:57:13.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\projet(essai final).lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\projet(essai final).unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  projet(essai final).cpp
1>c:\users\sondes\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\projet(essai final)\projet(essai final).cpp(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gmp.h': No such file or directory
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: You must, either get MPIR, or get a different compiler such as MinGW or Cygwin/gcc. What you are trying now will never work.

Comment: I am using visual c++ and cygwin, it works fine. You can google it on how to install that. It is not that difficult. Just install cygwin with gcc, make, m4. and run the configure in GMP. You need to edit some Project properties in visual c++ though